# Are there any Erlang written Zookeeper equivalent projects?

Tags: erlang

There are a few Zookeeper equivalent projects written in Go. [Etcd](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/getting-started-with-etcd/) for instance.

Erlang could also be a lightweight ideal distributed key-value store for specific configuration sharing and service discovery purpose, using Mnesia for instance. Are there any Erlang equivalents of Zookeeper ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any directly usable implementation of Zookeeper in Erlang but there are implementations of the Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast (ZAB) protocol in erlang

1. Extension of [riak_core](https://github.com/basho/riak_core) to use ZAB - [riak_zab](https://github.com/jtuple/riak_zab)
2. Standalone implementation of the protocol - [zab_engine](https://github.com/xinmingyao/zab_engine)

Note that I have not used any of the above personally and do not know about the completeness or correctness of the implementation

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Raft protocol:

https://github.com/andrewjstone/rafter

It is an Erlang implement of the Raft protocol which can be used to maintain consensus among a set of nodes.